# How do I disabled this prompt message on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of notifications pop up

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Office 365 settings. In the settings page, you can disable the notifications as below:

[image]

Here, you can disable the notifications that you want by unchecking them.

[image]

After unchecking, click on Save. The notifications will be turned off.

Comment: I have gone in to a users account and tried to look for that option but no joy. I went into the share-point admins account and turned it off saved it and then logged into account which receives the notification and it still pops up

Comment: Can you go to the url as in the 2nd screenshot? You have disabled notification for admins account right now. So to disable it for a user, login to site as user and go to https://portal.office.com/account/#settings

Comment: Users don't have that option